# How to convert text to date in MM-YYYY format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a column in Excel with the following entries in **text** format:

```
 7.2013
 7.2014
 8.2013
 8.2014
 9.2013
 9.2014
10.2013
10.2014
11.2013
11.2014
12.2013
12.2014
 1.2015
```

How can I convert this text to *date* and have them displayed in `mm-yyyy` format?

I tried changing it to Custom format `Format Cells > Numbers > Custom` but using it in the first cell (`7.2013`) gets changed to `01-1900`.

Answer (score 5):

Dates are stored as a number: days since January 0, 1900 (day 1 is 1/1/1900).  Times are stored as a decimal fraction of a day.  So 7.2013 is January 7, 1900 4:49:52 AM.  Formatting that as MM-YYYY gives you 01-1900.

Select the full column and do a *Search - Replace* for `.` to `-`.

This converts your number into a text string that Excel recognizes as month-year input and stores it as an appropriate date.  Now you can apply the Custom format `mm-yyyy` to the column.

Comment: Added some explanation.  Feel free to roll back or play with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your data, use this function:

```
=DATEVALUE((IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,2))=".",LEFT(A1),LEFT(A1,2)))&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Assuming that "A1" is your cell.

Afterwards, change the format...

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine (64 bit Excel 2010 on Win 7)

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1 , "." , "/"))
```

It should work whether the column is stored as text or not.

Another option is this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4) , LEFT(A1,2) , 1)
```

This works even without the leading spaces on the month, because the `LEFT(A1,2)` picks up `7.` which is interpreted as `7.0` and so still works as a month.